# Is there a method in numpy that computes the mean on every 2d array from a 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy

For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[[4,5,6],[7,8,7]]])

print(a.shape)
# (2, 2, 3)
```

So, on every 2d grid (3 grids on the example above) i want ot compute the mean:

```
mean = [np.mean(a[:, :, i]) for i in range(3)]
print(mean)
# [3.25, 4.25, 4.75]
```

Is there a method in numpy that achieves this?

I tried using mean on the axis but the result is not as expected.

Comment: Use `axis` parameter with `np.mean` - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

Comment: This can be done using a parameter `axis`: `mean = np.mean(a, axis=(0,1))`

Comment: thx, i didn't know  that i can pass the tuple for the axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `np.mean(axis = ...)` and specifying a tuple of dimensions to average over

```py
a.mean(axis=tuple(range(len(a.shape) - 1)))
```

This will compute the mean on every dimension/axis except the last one (note how the range of axis indices goes from `0` up to `len - 1` (exclusive) thus ignoring the last axis.

---

This method is extensible to deeper arrays. For example if you have an array of shape `(2, 6, 5, 4, 3)`, it will compute mean as `a.mean(axis=(0, 1, 2, 3))` thus giving you an array of 3 means (corresponding to 3 elements in the last dimension)